# Given an array,find the number of element it can divide or divided by the remaining elements of the array

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures, dynamic-programming

```
Input Array: int A={2,3,4,5,6} , array is not always sorted.

output Array:{2,1,1,0,2}
```

- since we can see `A[0]` can divide 4 & 6 so it has output 2.
- `A[1]` can divide only 6 ,it has output 1.
- `A[2]` is divided by 2,so has output 1.
- `A[3]` is not able to divide or being divided so has output 0.
- `A[4]` is being divided by 2 & 3,so has output 2.

I'm able to solve it using brute force approach which has time complexity of o(n*n). what could be the most efficient way to solve it. thank you.
my code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    //Function to return output vector
    vector<int>solve(vector<int> &A) {
        vector<int>v;
        for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<A.size();j++){
                if(i!=j){
                    if(A[j]%A[i]==0 || A[i]%A[j]==0){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            v.push_back(count);
        }
        return v;
    }
    
    int main(){
        vector<int>v={2,3,4,5,6};
        vector<int>s;
        s=solve(v);
    //printing the output array
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
            cout<<s[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: no it's not sorted, second sample test case was unordered.

Comment: Some kind of memoization or dynamic programming? Since you already divide all the rest of the numbers with `A[0]` you don't have to do it again.

Comment: What's the range each element is chosen from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible for your problem but how about something like

```
namespace {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<size_t>> const factors{
        {1, {1}},
        {2, {1}},
        {3, {1}},
        {4, {1, 2}},
        {5, {1}},
        {6, {1, 2, 3}},
    };
}

std::vector<int>solve(std::vector<int> &A) {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<size_t>> indexedFactors;
    size_t idx = 0;
    for(auto num: A) {
        // Lookup the factors of num from the table
       for(auto factor: factors.at(num)) {
           //  and add them to the map with indexes pointing to the number that has them as a factor
           indexedFactors[factor].push_back(idx);
       }
       ++idx;
    }
    std::vector<int> res(A.size());
    idx = 0;
    for(auto num: A) {
        if (indexedFactors.find(num) != indexedFactors.end()) {
            for(auto i: indexedFactors.at(num)) {
                res[i]++; // Track the divides
                res[idx]++; // Track the divided by
            }
        }
        ++idx;
    }
    return res;
}
```

You could have a pre-computed table of numbers and their factors (`factors` in the code). Don't have the number itself as a factor of itself added to the list.

Then you could iterate over the input array and add the factors of each number to a map and keep on adding the index of numbers of which they are a factor. e.g. If `num` is 6, then you add 1, 2, and 3 to the map with the index of 6 in the input array. Do this for all the numbers.

Now, iterate over the input array, and then for each number check if it's in the `indexedFactors` map and increment the count in the result array at all those indices. This takes care of the *divides* part. Also, increment the count for each of these times to take care of the *divided by* part. e.g. If `num` is 2 then it would have the indices of 4 and 6 within the input array, and these indices would be updated in the result array. But since 2 divides 4, 4 is divisible by 2 too, and hence increase the count in the result array at the index of 2.

The complexity is `O(n * m)` where `m` is the number of factors of each number in the input array (~ `√num`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I hope it would have worked. but finding factors of all the numbers and storing them in a map takes additional time and space complexity.

Comment: @def__init__ What's the range of numbers? You can pre-compute them and save time in generating them.  Also how many numbers can there be in the input? But true, the space complexity is high.

Answer (score 1):

Simple modification helps to remove a half of iterations, but complexity remains quadratic.

It seems there is no way to solve this problem faster (with factorization etc)

```
 make v: vector of A.size zeros
 ...
      for(int j=i+1;j<A.size();j++){
         if(A[j]%A[i]==0 || A[i]%A[j]==0){
             increment v[i] and v[j]
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, upvoted your kind answer, it was asked in my online coding round, I hope it would have worked but not sure it would have passed all their test cases.

Answer (score 0):

For `is divided by`, reference a count of each element; find the divisors of each element and add the count of any matches.

For `divides`, reference a count of each seen divisor; add the count of any matches of the element.

O(n * sqrt m) where m is max(input).